# Hour changes when rbind.fill is used to merge two files

Tags: r

I have two data frames.

The first is only three columns and 478 rows.

The second is four columns and 990 rows.

When I merge these using rbind.fill I end up with the POSIXct data in the second file having the hour changed from 05 to 01 in the merged data.frame.  The minutes and seconds are correct.

The "time" columns in both files are class POSIXct, I used orgin="1970-01-01" and tz="EDT" to set the class in both data.frames.  The two files where imported into R from .xls files using XLConnect.

Can anyone suggest what is causing this?

head(htsdata)

time oil.tempF gap

1 2016-04-14 06:48:45      69.6   a

2 2016-04-14 06:49:45      70.3   a

3 2016-04-14 06:50:45      70.0   a

4 2016-04-14 06:51:45      70.0   a

5 2016-04-14 06:52:45      69.4   a

6 2016-04-14 06:53:45      70.0   a

head(htsdata3)

time oil.tempF rm.tempF gap

*1 2016-04-15 05:48:30      69.1     69.1   b

2 2016-04-15 05:49:00      69.1     69.1   b

3 2016-04-15 05:49:30      68.7     68.9   b*

4 2016-04-15 05:50:00      68.9     68.7   b

5 2016-04-15 05:50:30      68.7     68.5   b

6 2016-04-15 05:51:00      68.7     87.4   b

htsdata.m <- rbind.fill(htsdata,htsdata3)

head(htsdata.m[476:481,])

time oil.tempF gap rm.tempF

476 2016-04-14 14:43:45      70.9   a       NA

477 2016-04-14 14:44:45      69.4   a       NA

478 2016-04-14 14:45:45      70.3   a       NA

*479 2016-04-15 01:48:30      69.1   b     69.1

480 2016-04-15 01:49:00      69.1   b     69.1

481 2016-04-15 01:49:30      68.7   b     68.9*